# New Extended WPFToolkit ColorPicker

Tags: wpf, controls

I've been trying to get the new colorpicker from the toolkit working in my app, without success...

Here is sample code that is supposed to pick up the color of the window background to populate current color, and upon new selection, is supposed to change the background color to the selected color...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200" xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended" 
        Name="Window" Background="blue">
    <Grid>
        <extToolkit:ColorPicker Name="colorPicker1" 
                                SelectedColor="{Binding ElementName=Window,Path=Background}" 
                                CurrentColor="{Binding ElementName=Window,Path=Background}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is all the documentation I've been able to locate on the colorpicker...
http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/15/extended-wpf-toolkit-new-colorpicker-control/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that Window.Background is a Brush and SelectedColor and CurrentColor is Color. You can get this to work by using a Converter.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200"   
        Name="Window" Background="blue">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BrushColorConverter x:Key="BrushColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <extToolkit:ColorPicker Name="colorPicker1"  
                                SelectedColor="{Binding ElementName=Window, 
                                    Path=Background, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource BrushColorConverter}}"
                                CurrentColor="{Binding ElementName=Window, 
                                    Path=Background, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource BrushColorConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the Converter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class BrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush brush = value as SolidColorBrush;
            return brush.Color;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Color color = (Color)value;
            return new SolidColorBrush(color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Meleak! You've helped me once again!

Answer (score 5):

The Convert function wasn't working for me, eventually this did the trick:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion resolved my similar issue on following line of my code when I was trying to set the color - from ColorPicker - of selected text: `myRichTxtBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, myColorPicker1.SelectedColor.Value);` The **Error** was `'Color' parameter type is not valid for formatting property 'Foreground'`. I surrounded `myColorPicker1.SelectedColor.Value` with `new SolidColorBrush(...)` and it resolved the problem. **Thank You** for coming to my rescue.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Meleak.  This question has also been answered in the [discussions](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=234350).

Also the ColorPicker has recently been updated. [Check it out.](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

That looks right at first glance. Try running your app in debug mode, and watch the Output window in Visual Studio for binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings as an intermediary. In your Settings.settings create a user scope parameter of type string. Name it BackColor1
Then create bindings for the control and for the element's background, both of them to the same setting (as below). The advantage is that the user gets a persistent setting. I want to precise that I tested it as a Grid row's background, not a window's but it should work the same.

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200" xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended" 
    Name="Window" 
    Background="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=BackColor1, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid>
       <extToolkit:ColorPicker  
         SelectedColor="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=BackColor1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```